# Local function - assigning variable

Tags: c#, c#-7.0

I would like to know whats the "correct" or the "recommended" way to write a local function that returns a value and assign this to a varial in the "parent" function. (What's the actual name of the "host" of the local function?)

I see the following 3 possibilities (maybe there are more):

- Use a variable inside the local function and return this at the end

  ```
  private void Foo()
  {
      int sum = Sum(1, 2);

      int Sum(int a, int b)
      {
          int localSum = a + b;
          return localSum;
          //I know I could write return a + b; but its just a simple demonstration
          //imagine something more complex, where you intialize an object and work with it in the "Sum" method and than want to return it
      }
  }
  ```
- Use the variable of the "parent" function and just set it and use a void function

  ```
  private void Foo()
  {
      int sum;
      Sum(1, 2);

      void Sum(int a, int b)
      {
          sum = a + b;
      }
  }
  ```
- Combine both above, to make it easier to read that `Sum` is setting the sum variable but drop the variable declaration in the local function

  ```
  private void Foo()
  {
      int sum = Sum(1, 2);

      int Sum(int a, int b)
      {
          sum = a + b;
          return sum;
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: This is very much opinion-based. I definitely wouldn't got with the last one though - it's confusing to do *both*. Pick one or the other - return or mutate.

Comment: I'd definetely prefer first one. Second case is like using global variables to share state. If that function would be any longer - you have no idea what effect it actually has without digging into its source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we put your first two code examples into SharpLab, we can see what the compiler lowers the code to:

[For code sample 1](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwD4AEAMACFBGA3AWACgUBmLAJgwGEMiBvIjJjABwQEsA3CeLAFgwAxAPbCAFAEpGzBoWbyM7AHYwMUAK5gMAXgwBlTWOwAaDOQkFC0hYpX7Dy1RFOOMwKXJsZZXha4A2wgDGEP4GWroQGADUbpa+8igA7BiBIWGa8V4AvtYYuYTZQA===):

```
public class C
{
    private void Foo()
    {
        C.<Foo>g__Sum|0_0(1, 2);
    }

    [CompilerGenerated]
    internal static int <Foo>g__Sum|0_0(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

[For code sample 2](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwD4AEAMACFBGA3AWACgUBmLAJgwGEMiBvIjJjABwQEsA3CeLAFgwAxAPbCAFAEpGzBoWbyM7AHYwMUAK5gCchUwDKmsdgA0GchO3TdKAQbBjlqiKccZgUnbtm7dGsBgBeDAgMAGo3bR8MAF8rGKJooA==):

```
public class C
{
    [CompilerGenerated]
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Auto)]
    private struct <>c__DisplayClass0_0
    {
        public int sum;
    }

    private void Foo()
    {
        C.<>c__DisplayClass0_0 <>c__DisplayClass0_;
        C.<Foo>g__Sum|0_0(1, 2, ref <>c__DisplayClass0_);
    }

    [CompilerGenerated]
    internal static void <Foo>g__Sum|0_0(int a, int b, ref C.<>c__DisplayClass0_0 ptr)
    {
        ptr.sum = a + b;
    }
}
```

In the second example, there is the slight overhead of creating a struct, in which `sum` is stored.

Aside from that, it really is subjective as to which is "best". In my view, sample 1 is the easier to understand. Whether you agree though is purely a matter of opinion.

The only thing that I'd express a strong opinion on is to not do option 3. Re-using the same name, `sum` is just plain confusing in my view. Again, that's pure opinion though.

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer would be: if you can write your functions so they don't need to modify member variables, you'll find they're easier to test and less likely to impact the behaviour of the rest of your program in unexpected ways.
For something like your example, one of the few good reasons I can think of for storing the result of a calculation in a member variable is if it's particularly expensive to do, and you need to the use the result at various unspecified points in the future.

Answer (score 0):

First way seems the most legit, because it does not violate the query-command separation principle. If the return type of a method is `Int32`(3rd example), I would expect that method not to change any state, however it does change the value of the variable out of its scope. Second example is better, but still too implicit. If your goal is to return something - return it. It is not your responsibility to care about what happens next.